# how to create a copy of json object in javascript instead of a reference

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

i have testdata.js file with json test data as below:

testdata.js file:

```
module.exports =
```

{
        createHost:
        {

```
        name : "System-001",
        description: "Creating System",

    }
```

}

In another test, I am trying to create a variable called testcase1 with the above test data. Changing the property value in testcase1, changes the value in the testdata.js file json object.

```
it("Create a host", function(){
var testcase1 = testdata.createHost;

testcase1.name="sys-002";

console.log(testcase1.name);
console.log(testdata.createHost.name);
});
```

Response:
sys-002
sys-002

My requirement is to create a copy of testdata instead of creating a reference. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shortest way:

```
var copied = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
```

Comment: Thanks **@Azamantes** for your answer.It worked ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for in` loop to loop through each of the properties and assign them by value.

```js
var createHost = { name : "System-001", description: "Creating System" }
var test = {};
for (var key in createHost)
 test[key] = createHost[key];
  
test.name = "Test";

console.log(test.name);
console.log(createHost.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extend function in jQuery to clone the object:

```
var testCaseClone = jQuery.extend({}, testdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "JSON object" (unless you literally mean global object that holds `parse` and `stringify` functions). There are only JSON strings. As such you copy them using simple `=` operator.

```
var copy_json_string = original_json_string
```

If you need to copy an object instead (it is **object**, just **object**, not "JSON object"), there are dozens of answers already, for example at: [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object).